# how I can use header.php and footer.php outside from wordpress theme directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a theme installed in wordpress like this directory `/wp-content/themes/mytheme` so in the root I have custom code which is little complex and easy to integrate in wordpress theme so I want to finding an option where I can use `header.php` and `footer.php` in root directory like this way. `/custom_code/custom.php`

Comment: So is the question - can I require header.php and footer.php by requiring single file: custom.php ?

Comment: @sitilge I want to outside from wordpress.

Comment: No problems - wp is a set of files, .php mostly. `require('/path/to/file/in/wp/dir/header.php');`

Comment: @sitilge No it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of searching here is the solution.

```js
<?php require('../wp-blog-header.php'); ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-

transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo

('charset'); ?>" />
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?> » Blog Archive <?php } ?> <?php

wp_title(); ?></title>

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body>
It works!

</body>
</html>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you include the header after the <head> tag? `And It Works!` should be `<p>It Works!</p>`

Comment: @ViperCode why should not include after header any specific reason I want to add some JS files in newer files then how I can?

Comment: Whichever one has the HTML in it should come after the `</head>` tag. All your scripts should be included in the `<head></head>`

Answer (score 0):

Include header.php and footer.php like this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_Wordpress_with_Your_Website

From the page:

```
<?php 
/* Short and sweet */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```